# Tensorflow for Poets (Retraining Inception) on Windows

Tags: python, windows, machine-learning, tensorflow

When I follow the tutorials of ["How to Retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories"](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining), I am running [`python retrain.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) on Windows. I have not made any changes to the file `retrain.py`. I get the following error after nearly 7300 bottleneck files are created

```
Creating bottleneck at /tmp/bottleneck\daisy\9204730092_a7f2182347.jpg.txt
Creating bottleneck at /tmp/bottleneck\daisy\99306615_739eb94b9e_m.jpg.txt
7300 bottleneck files created.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "retrain.py", line 930, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "retrain.py", line 846, in main
    bottleneck_tensor)
  File "retrain.py", line 755, in add_final_training_ops
    variable_summaries(layer_weights, layer_name + '/weights')
  File "retrain.py", line 711, in variable_summaries
    tf.scalar_summary('mean/' + name, mean)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'scalar_summary'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [tf.summary.scalar()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/scalar) instead of tf.scalar_summary.

Find list of all such updated summary functions [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration)

Comment: Welcome. If this worked, you may want to up vote and accept the answer :-)

Comment: Having reputation less than 15 :(

Comment: No problem.. U can do that afterwards.. :-)